# How do I iterate through an NSString in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

How can iterate through an NSString object in Objective c whiling maintaining an index for the character I am currently at?

I want to increment the ASCII value of every third character by 3, and then print this incremented character in a label in my user interface.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wasn't clear whether you just wanted to print the incremented characters or all. If the former, here's is how you would do it:

```
NSString *myString = @"myString";
NSMutableString *newString = [NSMutableString string];
for (int i = 0; i < [myString length]; i++) 
{
    int ascii = [myString characterAtIndex:i];
    if (i % 3 == 0) 
    {
        ascii++;
        [newString appendFormat:@"%c",ascii];
    }
}
myLabel.text = newString;
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this, this is EXTREMELY slow running, and it gives you the numerical value, not the character value.

Comment: Had the wrong format char which I fixed. He has to put it into a label... how big/slow do you think this string is? Besides, he asked for Objective-c.

Comment: @Richard Beware pre-mature optimization.

Comment: and like the other answer uses variables named fooUTF8 without using UTF8 this code uses a variable named ascii for something that is not necessarily ascii ^^

Answer (score 2):

Will this do the trick?

```
NSString *incrementString(NSString *input)
{
    const char *inputUTF8 = [input UTF8String]; // notice we get the buffers so that we don't have to deal with the overhead of making many message calls.
    char *outputUTF8 = calloc(input.length + 1, sizeof(*outputUTF8));

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        outputUTF8[i] = i % 3 == 0 ? inputUTF8[i] + 3 : inputUTF8[i];
    }

    NSString *ret = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:outputUTF8];
    free(outputUTF8); // remember to free the buffer when done!
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Using a stack-allocated array like that is dangerous. If the string is too long, you'll smash the stack and crash. You should dynamically allocate a buffer (i.e. with `calloc()` or equivalent) and free it when done.

Comment: Considering that this fails if you pass an actual UTF8 string there are a lot of variables named UTF8 in that code ;-) `[NSString length]` returns the unicode length of the string. Not the length of its bytes.

Comment: There's that too--this should be iterating over the string's `unichar` values (use `sizeof(unichar)`, `-getCharacters:range:`, and `+stringWithCharacters:length:` for efficiency.)